# storage_api The file could not be uploaded

Tags: 7, files

I'm attempting to upload a a file using a custom context type that uses the storage class i defined thru the storage_api module.  For some reason the upload of an image to it is failing with "The file could not be uploaded."  I have the local file system as the initial container and should propagate to an s3 bucket after the upload.

I've tried the built in Content>Media> add file and that works fine.  i think the file lands in public://  However I want to use the storage class from the storage_api.

I see the following in the dblog when i attempt the file upload that fails:

> Message: The upload directory storage-field-corp-image: for the file
>   field field_corp_image could not be created or is not accessible. A
>   newly uploaded file could not be saved in this directory as a
>   consequence, and the upload was canceled.

Not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue.  Turns out the Directory Path in the local container, which is the initial container, for the storage class the content type is using NEEDS to have a trailing slash. As in:

sites/default/files/storage/

instead of:

sites/default/files/storage

it's that picky.  and the log does not say its the issue.  it just says it had trouble accessing the field.  I found it by trial and error.

I hope this helps someone.